How to block the back button of android device when using AutoTabsScaffold
Flutter: 3.19.5
auto_route: 8.1.3
When in tabs, I don't want the device's back button to work
I tried using PopScope for the total page and for each individual page but still couldn't block it.
I don't know what's special about AutoTabsScaffold and if there is any property that can block this back
        AutoRoute(
                  path: 'a',
                  page: A.page,
                  children: [
                    AutoRoute(
                      initial: true,
                      page: B.page,
                    ),
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: C.page,
                    ),
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: D.page,
                    ),
              
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: E.page,
                    ),
                    AutoRoute(
                      page: F.page,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),



AutoTabsScaffold(
                routes: [
                  B(),
                  C(),
                  D(),
                  E(),
                  F(),
                ],
                bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
                  return BottomNavigationBar(...);
                }, `enter code here`
              ),

